# <A good appetite> and <a good metabolism> VS <good appetite> and <good metabolism>

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language, collocations

Dictionaries say both **"appetite"** and **"metabolism"** are variable nouns. Do you think we can say these sentences interchangeably?

> **I have a good appetite.**

> **I have good appetite.**

And can we say these sentences interchangeably?

> **I have a good metabolism.**

> **I have good metabolism.**

Is which of these sentences we can say about idiomacy rather than grammaticality since the nouns are variable nouns?

Comment: _I have a good appetite_ is much more idiomatic. Metabolism isn't exactly a common topic in everyday conversation, but I think we would use the article when referring to a particular person's metabolism.

Comment: @KateBunting And this is a matter of idiomacy, right. I mean I think we don't have to use the article with some other variable nouns that receive an adjective in my experience.

Comment: Without "a", the appetite example is glaringly wrong, in my opinion. Maybe elsewhere (outside the U.S.) in the English-speaking world it comes off otherwise. Metabolism sounds almost as bad too me.

Comment: I see that a 'variable noun' is one that can be either countable or uncountable. When referring to an individual's desire for food, I would say that _appetite_ was definitely countable.